# Change post header depending post status in Admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom post type:

```
register_post_type(
        'myplugin_po',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array(''),
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-pressthis',
            'menu_position' => 56,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Purchase orders',
                'singular_name' => 'Purchase orders',
                'add_new' => 'Add new purchase order',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new purchase order',
                'new_item' => 'New purchase order',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit purchase order',
                'search_items' => 'Search purchase orders',
                'item_updated' => 'Purchase order updated',
                'item_published' => 'Purchase order published'
            ),
        )
    );
```

How can I set 'edit_item' value to 'Edit purchase order' for *'draft'* post status and 'Purchase order' for *'publish'* post status on **post.php** admin page ?

Comment: Leave it as is there and change it in admin when you're able to check the page status.  I'm fairly certain that post types register too early to check.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65652/60844

Comment: @TonyDjukic I know get_post_status() function, I don't know hook or filter to change  'edit_item' field

Comment: What I’m suggesting is that you leave this as is, but then use something like gettext (https://pippinsplugins.com/introduction-gettext-filter-wordpress/) to manipulate the label later on, when the CPTs are being displayed in the admin.